# I want to load the first tab of my tabbed shopping cart

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I have a tabbed interface for changing categories in a shopping cart. The active tab is highlighted when clicked, and the previous tab goes back to normal. I want the first tab to be already selected when the user visits the page.
[My Shopping Cart](http://www.droodslist.com/admin/theresheglowsshoppingcart/Feb14/skin-care-products.htm)

```
<div class="tabs">
<button type="button" class="tab" onclick="selectTab(this);">Cleansers</button>
<button type="button" class="tab" onclick="selectTab(this);">Toners</button>
<button type="button" class="tab" onclick="selectTab(this);">Astringents</button>
<button type="button" class="tab" onclick="selectTab(this);">Exfoliators</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var selectedTab = null;
function selectTab(tab) {
 tab.blur();
 if (selectedTab) { selectedTab.className = 'tab'; }
 tab.className = 'tab-selected';
 selectedTab = tab;
 // call ajax to load products
}
</script>
```

I tried setting the class property to tab-selected like this

```
<button type="button" class="tab-selected" onclick="selectTab(this);">Cleansers</button>
```

but it remains highlighted when I click the other tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/).
It is much easier and your javascript code would be more "manageable".

Answer (score 0):

this might help

[Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

I guess when you highlighting first tab on page load, variable "selectedTab" is still null

Answer (score 0):

This will work even if the tabs are changed. I used button elements for tabs, but it will work for any element when you need the first one.

```
<body onload="selectTab(document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0]);" >
```